# Dataset or Statistics Mode

Tags: anylogic

I expected this question to have a really straightforward answer but can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

I need to be able to get the mode of a dataset or a statistics element. All I can find is min, max, mean and median.

Is there no function that gives the mode?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the below function, but I still find it weird that the mode function is not built-in...

```
int maxCount=0;

for(int i=0; i<QueueLengthDailyMaq.size(); ++i)
{
    int count=0;

    for(int j=0; j<QueueLengthDailyMaq.size(); ++j)
    {
        if(QueueLengthDailyMaq.getY(j) == QueueLengthDailyMaq.getY(i))
        {
           count++;
        }

        if(count > maxCount)
        {
            maxCount = count;
            mode = QueueLengthDailyMaq.getY(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is in fact the only way